# Is it possible to have both static and dynamic IPv6 addresses on one interface?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, ipv6, qemu

I have two Qemu virtual machines with Ubuntu Server. I would like one of them to be a DHCP server. On the second one, I would like to have two IPv6 addresses. One should be static, and the other one should be obtained from my DHCP server. I am able to create many static addresses, but when I get a dynamic one, I lose all my static addresses except a link-local one. What should I do to have both static and dynamic IPv6 addressess on one interface?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: u may use a virtual device like eth0:0 and set it to dhcp as it is easy to to: auto eth0:0 and second line iface eth0:0 inet dhcp ans this must be added to network/interfaces as i am not using the network manager and the end is that you have multi ips for the dame device unlike windows as im nit knowing that this might be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How IPv6 addresses are auto configured depends on the [flags in the ICMPv6 RA](https://blogs.infoblox.com/ipv6-coe/slaac-to-basics-part-2-of-2-configuring-slaac/).

To have the host both request from DHCPv6, and generate its own via SLAAC, you'll likely want to enable all the flags. Autonomous, Managed address configuration, and Other.  Plus a prefix information option. And static addresses on the host if desired.

Yes, this may be done with one interface. Linux has been capable of many IPs on one interface for a very long time. (Alias interfaces of the form `eth0:0` have been obsolete for just as long. Don't use `ifconfig` on Linux any more.)